# Blue line under input / select on safari

Tags: html, css, safari, mobile-safari

How to fix this weird blue underline (?) under input. It's only appears on safari mobile.
And appears every time after change / selected value.

[image]

Already tried:

```
 input{  
 outline : none
}

input:focus {
 outline-width: 0
}
```

Comment: Is it in web/mobile/responsive?

Comment: Try this (  outline-color: transparent)

Comment: it appears only safari mobile,